# parse erorr near '\n' in .zshrc file

Tags: zsh, zshrc

When I open my MacOS terminal, it shows

```
Last login: Sun Jan  2 15:50:48 on ttys000
/Users/rajeshrao/.zshrc:18: parse error near `\n'
(base) rajeshrao@Rajeshs-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I tried opening that `.zshrc` file which had this code in there ---->

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/rajeshrao/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/rajeshrao/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/rajeshrao/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/rajeshrao/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
 <<<conda initialize<<<
```

[here is the image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nMhC.png)

I don't know much about how shell works and am just a beginner. I didn't interfere with anything before using the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The last line has lost the initial '#' (ie. is not a comment).
Edit the file to end with this line:

```
# <<<conda initialize<<<
```

Comment: thanks bro , this seens to have worked , its not showing that error anymore

Comment: @RAVIKULRAORA2011051010071 Great! The next step on Stack Overflow then is to upvote the answer(s) that helped by clicking the up arrow and mark the answer as accepted by clicking the "check" symbol.